# Equilateral triangle given two points in 3D

Tags: triangles, 3d

Let's say I have two points: $A = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $B = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$.

How can I find a third point $C = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$ such that:
a) $A, B$ & $C$ form an equilateral triangle
b) the value of $z_2$ is the highest it can be

Yes so I'm looking for a 2d triangle in 3D space. So what I think I know is that the space of solutions that match criteria (a) fits on a 2d circle that emanates from $(A+B)/2$ of radius $||(A+B)/2||*sqrt(3)$. To match criteria (b) I've thought about iterating over the values of that circle until I find an approximation of the largest $z_2$ but am looking for a more closed-form solution.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  You need to include what you already know, what you have tried, where you are stuck.  It takes time and effort to format an answer so people would rather not waste effort explaining things you already know, or talking over your head.  You'll get downvotes instead of answers with just what looks like a homework problem with no effort put in.  Also, formatting tips are [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply! Yes so I'm looking for a 2d triangle in 3D space. So what I think I know is that the space of solutions that match criteria (a) fits on a 2d circle that emanates from (A+B)/2 of radius ||(A+B)/2||*sqrt(3). To match criteria (b) I've thought about iterating over the values of that circle until I find an approximation of the largest z_2 but am looking for a more closed-form solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

The third point  C lies on the straight line obtained by
simplifying

$$ (x-x1)^2+(y-y1)^2+(z-z1)^2=(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2+(z-z0)^2=(x1-x0)^2+(y1-y0)^2+(z1-z0)^2  $$

Comment: how do I answer criteria (b) then?

Comment: Derivative wrt x, y =0